# How to Find the Values of Some Constants of a Transformed Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling with this problem. I'm trying to find the value of the constants of a transformation.

If I initially have $y=f(x)$ (first plot) and this get transformed to $g(x) = Af(Bx+C) + D$ (second plot), how do I find those constants, I believe I can get values of $C$ and $D$ by knowing how much the point $(0,0)$ changes, but I'm not sure if I doing things right and also don't know how to find other values.

I would appreciate some help and thank you in advance.

[[image: <span class=]$y = f(x)$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBHwA.png)

[[image: <span class=]$g(x) = Af(Bx+C) + D$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujH26.png)

Comment: so what did you find for the values of $C$ and $D$?

Comment: i believe $C=0$ and $D=-1$.

Comment: ok that's right, and are you $100\%$ confident in your justification for why? Because if you are, I'll try to write up an answer only for the other two constants.

Comment: I'm not sure,the point $(0,0)$ it's transformed to $(0,-1)$ so there's only a shift on the $y-axis$ and that's for every values of $A$ and $B$ because we are dealing with the point $(0,0)$, that's what i believe

Comment: Do you have the graph only or the function g(x) as well?

Comment: just the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct that $C=0$ and $D=-1$.

Because of the intercepts of $f$ we can guess that

$$f(x)=ax(x^2-4)(x^2-1)$$

With a value of $a=1$ this is a good fit for the given graph.

Notice that on the graph of $g$ the horizontal distance between the left-most and right-most extreme points has been stretched by a factor of 3, indicating that $b\approx\frac{1}{3}$.

Furthermore, the vertical distance between the left-most and right-most peaks has decreased by a factor of $2$ suggesting that $A\approx-\frac{1}{2}$. (negative because $g$ is inverted)

Using desmos.com to graph

$$g(x)=-\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)-1$$

we get the following:

[image: transformed polynomial graph]